# Is it possible to make a Java SWT composite with an alpha value?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am developing a GUI in Java SWT for use in a 3D particle physics simulator. The current GUI is quite clunky and unattractive, as it consists of multiple windows. I would like to consolidate the GUI into one window with a canvas, however to preserve functionality I must also add composites on top of this canvas. For aesthetic reasons, I would like the composites to be semi-transparent. I have done quite a bit of research, however nothing has worked so far. Is this even feasible using the composite API, and If so, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: out of curiosity do you have to use SWT. I do not have much practise with it. Thought I have been playing with SwingX and they have lots of useful components. For example for some tools perfect would be JXMultiSplitPane. In [my answer to other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117826/jxmultisplitpane-how-to-use/6122377#6122377) I give a sample code which you can use to easily create a tool/IDE look if that is what you are after.

Comment: @Boro I don't _have_ to use SWT, however I am quite partial to it after using Swing for a small application with little success for the amount of work I put in. About SwingX- It looks incredibly nice, but it might be a little too bulky for what I am trying to do. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set the transparency of a Shell - Shell.setAlpha(int).

Are you sure that semi-transparent composites will work if they are static? Isn't the idea to have semi-transparency on a floating window?

Comment: Transparency _should_ not affect the function of a composite, but I would have to see the API (if it exists) to be sure. I would not use a semi-transparent window because the trimmings are too large and would detract from the GUI. Thanks for you input.